# Can I use Google Analytics for multiple versions of an application on different domains

Tags: google-analytics

We have a commercial web application which customers buy and host on different domains. I want to add google analytics tracking to all the instances of the application that will give me aggregate data across all versions of the application.

I am not interested in tracking the same users across the different domains (as a given user will only ever use one instance of the application).

Can I just set up a new analytics account and add it to all the instances of the application and it will just work?

One complication is that customers often want their own analytics tracking for their instance of the application. Therefore I am likely to need two trackers on each page (one for them and one aggregate one for me) which I am planning to tackle using this approach:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers

Answer (score 1):

That's easier using Google Analytics Beacon.

You can put a 1x1 transparent image anssociated to a specific url and your Google Analytics ID to track  any click or event over tour webapp.